# Reduce big dataset (like open images) for object detection of few classes

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, object-detection

I'm quite new to Machine Learning and try to write my own neural network for object detection. I have downloaded the [Open Images dataset](https://github.com/openimages/dataset), but I only need a very small set of classes to be detected. Therefore I want to reduce the size of the dataset, because I don't want the resulting model to detect a pizza or some other objects, that are not relevant for my specific task.

I am not sure whether I should delete only the labels of the classes that I don't need or also all Images that are labeled with this classes. In fact I only need 3 Classes, but the dataset contains like 600 different classes with bounding boxes. And I don't really know how I should modify the dataset so that it becomes reasonable for training my model.

Comment: Yes, you should also delete the images that have those unwanted labels. Deleting only the labels and not the images/data will yield an unlabelled set of data which cannot be used for classification anymore. Also since your dataset contains 600 classes I assume it must be a huge dataset so remove unwanted data programmatically.